# C# WinForms: Adding rows to a dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, rows

I've just started to use dataGridView, and some things seem strange to me:

- when there is a Columns property, in which you can add columns, why is there not a Rows property? It seems you can only add rows programmatically. Or am I wrong?
- the 'star' icon to the left of the first row, can't it be removed?
- is it possible to disable sorting? I mean when you click on a column, the "sorting-arrow" appears, suggesting that the cells would be sorted.

If it is only possible to add rows programmatically, I have this question:

- I need a dataGridView with 1 column and x rows. How to do this the quickest and easiest way? The cells will be filled at runtime, programmatically.

**update:** About disabling sorting, I found out myself: there is a property to change this if you open the (Collections) of the columns.

Comment: Have you reviewed this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148854/adding-rows-to-datagridview-with-existing-columns

Comment: String[] dataSource = new String[x]; Bind the array to the DataGridView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add Rows by calling `dataGridView1.Rows.Add();`. For multiple rows there is an overload for the same available. `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(5);`

Now to fill the `dataGridView1` rows you can either assign a DataSource and set the `DataPropertyName` for the Column.
Else loop through and fill the data cell wise like `dataGridView1[columnindex,rowindex].Value =something`

The star icon shows the current row which is being edited, you can choose to hide that cell by setting the `RowHeadersVisible` to false.

Comment: nice answer and this may help : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx . first it is better to check msdn and look for "members", each member has already a website like Rows : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx . enjoy !

Comment: Thanks, so I guess it's only possible to add rows programmatically. Ok, I have added 4 rows, each with a different HeaderCell value. When I start the program, the names/values are not totally visible, but I can enlarge the width of that row (I'm just calling it a row although its index is actually -1) manually. Can this be done in code? I've tried various AutoSizeColumnsModes, but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Comment: You mean the width of the column?  Rows don't have widths.  Setting width can definitely be done in code.  `dataGridView1.Columns[index].Width = value`

Comment: @harlam357, this would work if the index weren't actually -1. You know, the width of the "column" I need to change is the leftmost column, _not_ the first column with cells beneath.